# Proc Logistic: Ranking Strength of Predictors

Tags: sas, logistic-regression

I have built a model using Proc logistic and I need to rank the strength of predictors.  Should I be looking for something in one of the outputs? Or is there some code that will calculate the strength?

Comment: I may not be understanding your question, but wouldn't your standardized regression coefficients be the weights you can use to rank your predictors?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, would you mind giving me an example?  I'm never used standardize weights to rank my predictors - I'm very new to this, .  I'm using SAS by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This document](http://www.mwsug.org/proceedings/2009/stats/MWSUG-2009-D10.pdf) explains how to use standardized coefficients to rank the predictors of a logistic regression model. In `proc logistic` you specify `stb` option to get the standardized coefficients and `ods output parameterestimates = params;` to get these in a table. Then you calculate the absolute values of the standardized coefficients and rank them from highest (stronger predictors) to lowest (weaker predictors).

```
PROC LOGISTIC DATA=SASHELP.JUNKMAIL;
    MODEL CLASS = MAKE -- CAPTOTAL / STB;
    ODS OUTPUT PARAMETERESTIMATES = PARAMS;
RUN;

DATA PARAMS;
    SET PARAMS;
    WHERE VARIABLE NE 'Intercept';
    ABSSTANDARDIZEDEST = ABS(STANDARDIZEDEST);
    KEEP VARIABLE STANDARDIZEDEST ABSSTANDARDIZEDEST;
RUN;

PROC RANK DATA=PARAMS OUT=RANKPARAMS DESCENDING;
   VAR ABSSTANDARDIZEDEST;
   RANKS RANK;
RUN;

PROC SORT DATA=RANKPARAMS;
    BY RANK;
RUN;

PROC PRINT DATA=RANKPARAMS NOOBS;
RUN;
```